# Run function on every route change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have an app built on angular.js, and I want to run a function whenever the route is changed and a new template is rendered in the view. I found a way to do it in a controller when it is activated, like this:

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(next, current){
    //...do stuff here...
});
```

But is there a way to run a function on each route change, so I only have to enter it once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your view

```
<div ng-app='myApp'>
   <ng-view/>
</div>
```

change it to

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='RootController'>
   <ng-view/>
</div>
```

In your `RootController` you can add the event handler for `$routeChangeStart`. Since your `RootController` is created once and remains for the lifetime of the app you can safely subscribe to this event here.

Answer (score 3):

I have a better solution. U can add a run block in your main file (where u define your app) and insert an event handeer for $routeChangeStart. This way u dont have to add anything to your html. see my exmaple:

```
yourAppNAme.run(function($rootScope) {
     $scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(next, current){
         //...do stuff here...
     });
});
```

this exmaple cheked and i currently working on my angularjs app.